# how to make a wpf combobox with the resource of an array of double?

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, binding

my Window has an array of double as a field :

```
double[] sizes = new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
```

and also a combo box which I want it to have exact Items as the array above.
can anyone help me with xaml binding this array as a resource for the combo box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what your code looks like but here's an example of how to bind an array to a `ComboBox`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sizes}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public double[] sizes = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        public double[] Sizes
        {
            get { return sizes; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nathan's answer, I'd like to add that if you'd want to bind to a static data, it's a good idea to specify binding mode as `OneTime` for performance reasons:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Sizes, Mode=OneTime}" />
</Grid>
```

See details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).